# How to enable WebDAV in Adobe AEM?

Tags: rmi, webdav, aem

I am trying to access Adobe AEM via WebDAV, however, I cannot get it to work.

I am running the out-of-the-box crx-quickstart, so I am using port 4502 and the default workspace.  I am using Windows Explorer as the WebDAV client, which I use to connect to Sharepoint without difficulty.

These seem to be the only instructions for connecting to AEM via WebDAV.
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/webdav_access.html

The instructions imply that you just point your WebDAV client at the following URL and you are golden. However, I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
http://localhost:4502/crx/repository/crx.default
```

Since this doesn't work, I have verified other settings.

For instance, within the OSGi configuration manager `http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr` I verified and clicked `Save` on various WebDAV settings.

```
Apache Sling Simple WebDAV Servlet
Root Path = "/crx/repository"

Apache Sling DavEx Servlet
Root Path = "/crx/server"
Use absolute URIs [X]
```

I also tried to work backwards from these instructions on how to disable WebDAV
http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DisableWebDAV.html

However, right away, it refers to `<cq5_home>/crx-quickstart/server/` and there is no `server` directory under the crx-quickstart directory.  Should I create this directory?

I also investigated this document on setting up Virtual Repositories.
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/administering/virtual_repository.html

However, I was still not able to get it to work and in fact, I couldn't get RMI working either (separate question, I guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `/crx/repository` path but WebDAV is also enabled on /, as demonstrated below on a vanilla AEM 5.6.1 instance. curl -T does a WebDAV PUT.

```
$ date > /tmp/somefile.txt
$ curl -u admin:admin -X MKCOL http://localhost:4502/tmp/test
$ curl -u admin:admin -T/tmp/somefile.txt http://localhost:4502/tmp/test/somefile.txt
$  curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/tmp/test/somefile.txt
Fri Jan 17 10:41:36 CET 2014
```

RMI would indeed be a separate question, and if you're hesitating between WebDAV and RMI you might want to expose your use case, as the Sling HTTP APIs might be good enough.

Comment: Hmm...These curl commands do in fact work. I haven't had trouble using Windows Explorer as a WebDAV client against Sharepoint, so I wonder what is different here.

Comment: I cannot help with the Windows client unfortunately, never use that. Connecting to the same test instance as above from a macosx 10.9.1 client works fine.

Comment: Indeed connecting directly from osx (finder - go - connect to server) works. Just make sure the protocol doesn't change from http to something like afp.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work from Windows Explorer you need to add a CRX user with the same user name and password as a Windows user that has permission to access the repository files. The Windows WebClient will ask you to logon at a Windows level. This userid must also exist in both Windows and CRX. Once I did this I was able to set up a shared drive to point to the CRX repository.

I also made a registry change to set the WebClient to use Basic authentication for SSL and non-SSL shares. Using the registry editor, for the key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters
set
BasicAuthLevel to 2.

Comment: I need to try this on a machine where I have permission to modify the registry, but from what I have read this seems correct.  It looks like Microsoft increased security by disabling Basic Auth by default. The WebClient service is not even installed on Windows Server 2008 by default. My guess is that you don't necessarily have to create a user, unless you don't want to be prompted for alternate authentication.

Comment: When I first set this up I did the registry change first but still could not access connect using the Windows WebClient and the admin/admin user. I added a Windows admin/admin user and it connected. But it does seem odd that this should be required. Have retested again with no Windows admin user and a reboot and I can now connect, so the first part of my answer does not seem to be right.

Comment: Thanks for the followup.  I was able to confirm that the registry change is all that is needed.  A reboot is likely required for the registry change to take effect.  In places where I can't change my registry, I just went with the portable version of CarotDAV http://rei.to/carotdav_en.html

Comment: Even when you get it to work the Windows WebClient is unusably slow. I also tried BitKinex which was faster but still did not seem to have the authentication right. CarotDAV is a much better solution.

Comment: You are right about the reboot. This is probably because the WebClient is running as a Windows service which needed to be restarted. Also this support note (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2445570) documents how to make the Windows WebClient more responsive. After doing this change it works quite well and makes any resources available through Explorer.