# Integrating MS Office tools like Outlook, Word etc with CQ

Tags: ms-office, integration, aem

{The ability to do direct edits locally in Office tools and getting those edits/changes/updates saved in CQ}

I have a requirement in my project that require a kind of way ,where I can Integrate CQ5 with MS Office.means whenever I do any changes in any MS tool(Word,Power Point, MS Excel) then all the changes automatically reflected inside the CQ5.

Is there any way to do this..or we have any plugin in MS Office that can help me in this requirement.

Quickly answers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can setup WebDAV to be able to edit Office documents directly in the JCR:

- http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/webdav_access.html
- [How to enable WebDAV in Adobe AEM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168723/how-to-enable-webdav-in-adobe-aem)